# how insert custom column with mybatis in pgsql

Tags: mybatis

my code like this

```
<select id = "getVideoOrgTreeChannels" resultMap="orgTreeChannels">
    select so.id id, so.company_name, so.company_code,
    ${sysCode} as sysCode,
    ${plateNo} as plateNo
    from sys_organization so
    where so.id=#{companyId}
    and so.company_status='0'
</select>
```

and the mybatis can not generate prepare sql。The error log  like this

```
SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2a7ed399] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
JDBC Connection [com.alibaba.druid.proxy.jdbc.ConnectionProxyImpl@700c3c28] will not be managed by Spring
==>  Preparing: select so.id id, so.company_name, so.company_code, as sysCode, as plateNo from sys_organization so where so.id=? and so.company_status='0' 
Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2a7ed399]
2023-01-31 15:59:20.549 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] ERROR c.g.boot.common.exception.GciBootExceptionHandler:55 - 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: sql injection violation, syntax error: ERROR. pos 62, line 1, column 51, token AS : select so.id id, so.company_name, so.company_code,
         as sysCode,
         as plateNo
        from sys_organization so
        where so.id=?
        and so.company_status='0'
### The error may exist in file [D:\workProject\gci_video_3\webSite\src\gci-video-web-service\gci-video-web\gci-boot-video-manage\target\classes\com\gci\boot\modules\video\mapper\xml\VideoBusinessDataMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.gci.boot.modules.video.mapper.VideoBusinessDataMapper.getVideoOrgTreeChannels
### The error occurred while executing a query
### SQL: select so.id id, so.company_name, so.company_code,          as sysCode,          as plateNo         from sys_organization so         where so.id=?         and so.company_status='0'
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: sql injection violation, syntax error: ERROR. pos 62, line 1, column 51, token AS : select so.id id, so.company_name, so.company_code,
         as sysCode,
         as plateNo
        from sys_organization so
        where so.id=?
        and so.company_status='0'
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; sql injection violation, syntax error: ERROR. pos 62, line 1, column 51, token AS : select so.id id, so.company_name, so.company_code,
         as sysCode,
         as plateNo
        from sys_organization so
        where so.id=?
        and so.company_status='0'; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: sql injection violation, syntax error: ERROR. pos 62, line 1, column 51, token AS : select so.id id, so.company_name, so.company_code,
         as sysCode,
         as plateNo
        from sys_organization so
        where so.id=?
        and so.company_status='0'
```

when I execute sql statement. it can insert column and my sql statement like this

```
select so.id as isd, so.company_name, so.company_code ,'syscode' as title from sys_organization so;
```

it can insert custom column successfully.

```
isd                |company_name|company_code|title  |
-------------------+------------+------------+-------+
1613079881513832449|测试公司        |A01         |syscode|
1613079972102410241|开发一部        |A01A01      |syscode|
1613080029140750337|开发二部        |A01A02      |syscode|
1613080075039019009|交通开发公司      |A02         |syscode|
1613089530539556865|技术一部        |A02A01      |syscode|
1613089567768199170|技术二部        |A02A02      |syscode|
1613089659170471937|技术三部        |A02A03      |syscode|
```

Comment: The error will be resolved if you use `#{}` (e.g. `#{sysCode} as sysCode`). BTW, the error message shows that the values of `sysCode` and `plateNo` are `null`. If that is unexpected, you may have to show us more code (e.g. how those parameters are prepared and how you call the method).

Comment: thank you reply。the #{}, ${} ,'${}' ，I've tried everything。the mybatis seems that can not handle the field before ‘from’ keyword. I have to be implemented through business code.

Comment: MyBatis can handle parameter references before `from` just fine. If you could create a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and share it on your GitHub repo, I would take a look when I have some time.